# Exporting data containing umlauts into a .csv which is readable by Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, encoding, utf-8

I am using *Python 2.7.2* on a *Mac OS X 10.8.2*. **I need to write a .csv file which often contains several "Umlauts" like ä, ö and ü.** When I write the .csv file Numbers and Open Office are all able to read the csv correctly and also display the Umlauts without any problems.

But if I read it with Microsoft Excel 2004 the words are display like that:

```
TuÃàrlersee
```

I know, Excel has problems dealing with UTF-8. I read something that Excel versions below 2007 are not able to read UTF-8 files properly, even if you have setted the UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Marker). I'm setting the UTF-8 BOM with the following line:

```
e.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)
```

So what I tried as next step was instead of exporting it as UTF-8 file I wanted to set the character encoding to mac-roman. With the following line I decoded the value from utf-8 and reencoded it with mac-roman.

```
projectName = projectDict['ProjectName'].decode('utf-8').encode('mac-roman')
```

But then I receive the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u0308' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>
```

**How can I export this data into a .csv where Excel is able to read also the Umlauts correctly?** Python internally handles everything in UTF-8. Or maybe I'm not understanding the decoding/encoding correctly. In Python 3.0 they have adapted the whole encoding/decoding  model, but I need to stay on version 2.7.2..

I am using the DictWriter like that:

```
w = csv.DictWriter(e, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore', delimiter=';', quotechar='\"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
w.writeheader()
```

Comment: Did you insert the UTF-8 BOM?

Comment: Yes, I have the following line included: e.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8). I also tested it with a newer Excel Version (2011) also there the Umlaut problem still exists.

Comment: Ok, did you verify from hex dump that the file was written correctly, starting with the bytes `0xef 0xbb 0xbf ...`

Comment: Does the `UnicodeWriter` from the docs help? - http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples

Comment: Looks correct: 0000000 ef bb bf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\u0308` is a combining diaeresis; you'll need to [normalize your unicode string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) before decoding to mac-roman:

```
import unicodedata

unicodedata.normalize('NFC', projectDict['ProjectName'].decode('utf-8')).encode('mac-roman')
```

Demo, encoding a `ä` character in denormalized form (`a` plus combining diaeresis) to mac-roman after normalization to composed characters:

```
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', u'a\u0308').encode('mac-roman')
'\x8a'
```

I've used this technique in the past to produce CSV for Excel for specific clients where their platform encoding was known upfront (Excel will interpret the file in the current Windows encoding, IIRC). In that case I encoded to `windows-1252`.

Comment: It's working! The only thing I have now is the BOM Is visible in the Excel Table at the beginning. But I guess this is only in the older Excel versions. Like 2004 I have here on this machine. Thanks again. Finally I can enjoy my christmas holidays ;).

Comment: Good answer - I can see this being useful later on for others +1

Answer (score 0):

CSV files are really only meant to be in ASCII - if what you're doing is just writing out data for import into Excel later, then I'd write it as an Excel workbook to start with which would avoid having to muck about with this kind of stuff.

Check http://www.python-excel.org/ for the `xlwt` module.

Comment: If you know your target CSV reader, using encodings is perfectly fine, but you need to know what encodings they support.

Comment: @MartijnPieters agreed - but if the aim's to write to Excel - just write it to Excel to start with... (and version '97 is openable by most other spreadsheet programs anyway)

Comment: When you don't need formatting, CSV is so much lighter to generate. I've done this in the past encoding to `windows-1252` for specific clients.

Comment: Yeah, this will be my backup plan. Thanks for the fast answer!